# Laravel Query Binding Reuse

Tags: laravel, sqlsrv

Hi on Laravel 7 with sqldrv driver.
I have a large query and i use a lot of bindings, some the same multiples times in query like ids and stamps.

Example :
`$query=... var = :id ... INSERT INTO ... foo = :i ... WHERE toni = :i ... ";  $bindings =["id" => 123];`

When i tried do run the query `DB::statement($query, $bindings);`, i get this error : `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[07002]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (SQL:`

I read that i can add in config\database.php  `'options' => [ PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true, ]`, but it not work, maybe because it's sqlsrv driver.
I could also declare and set variable in the header of the SQL queries, but i think it's an effort that is unnecessary.

Is there anyway to reuse bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the question using SQL Variables, I declare them on top and use it everywhere on the query. So i use only one binding per variable.

`DECLARE @cBOstamp as varchar(25) = :bostamp`

The only problem i see on this, is variable declaration type. You must always type your variables.